# file does not have buffer interface

Tags: python, django

i have a function in my views.py. It is like this

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
def get_file(self, url):
    # pdb.set_trace()
    result = urllib.urlretrieve(url)
    fi = open(result[0])
    fi_name = os.path.basename(url)
    suf = SimpleUploadedFile(fi_name, fi)
    return suf
```

while creating SimpleUploadedFile object i get the error saying

```
TypeError: file doesnot have buffer interface
```

I tried changing open mode to 'rb'. But still get the same error
Plz help me out

Answer (score 10):

[SimpleUploadedFile](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/files/uploadedfile.py#L112) needs the actual file content, rather than a file object. So you could fix your code like this:

```
suf = SimpleUploadedFile(fi_name, fi.read())
```

I must say though I don't know why you are using urlretrieve, which saves the content to a local temp file which you then must open and read. Better to use `urlopen` and pass it directly:

```
result = urllib.urlopen(url)
fi_name = os.path.basename(url)
suf = SimpleUploadedFile(fi_name, result.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem on the dreaded El Capitan, in the requests lib.
It seems that passing unicode as HTTP content breaks stuff when converted to memoryview() on the socket layer.
Just passing everything as plain strings fixed it for me.